# How can I get data from an Json array in DOJO?

Tags: javascript, json, dojo

I have a small question :

If I have a JSON array:

```
{
"cate_user_res_id": "4",
"from": "url",
"mimetype": "image/jpeg",
"ext": "jpg",
"res_name": "http://watermarked.cutcaster.com/cutcasterglobe.jpg",
"user_id": "1",
"file_size": 55966,
"created": "2011-12-19 03:29:45",
"type": "i"
}
```

How can i get data of `["res_name"]` index?

I alert `data['res_name']` it result undefined.

Thanks for any suggestion!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to parse to Javascript object first from the JSON array.

```
//var data = JSON.parse("<JSON string>");
var data = JSON.parse('{ "res_name" : " stackoverflow" }');

//Then you can get your value easily.
console.log(data.res_name);
console.log(data['res_name']);
```

Answer (score 4):

Check this tutorial, would be helpful:
http://geochalkboard.wordpress.com/2009/08/03/reading-json-data-with-dojo/

Answer (score 3):

```
var obj = dojo.fromJson(json);
console.log(obj.res_name);
```